# how to load a large xls file in android?

Tags: android, excel

I try to read an xls file which contains 80k cells in android , however it appears the following error message : FATAL EXCEPTION : main
                             java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

What should I do in order to read the xls file successfully?

Thanks in advance,
Anestis

```
 public class ReadExcelFile
    {
      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

      public ReadExcelFile()
      {

          Workbook workbook1 = null;
          WorkbookSettings s = null;
          InputStream excelContent = null;
      try {
          excelContent = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/product/sopho/lexiko.xls");
          s = new WorkbookSettings();
          s.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(true);
          workbook1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(excelContent,s);
          Sheet sheet = workbook1.getSheet(0);       
          ExcelMap(sheet);
          ExcelKeyList(sheet);

      } catch(Exception e) {

      } finally {

          if(workbook1 != null) {
              workbook1.close();
          }
          if(excelContent != null) {
              try {
                excelContent.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {}
          }

      }
  }



  private void ExcelKeyList(Sheet sheet)
  {
      for (int i=0; i<80001; i++)
      {
          list.add(sheet.getCell(0,i).getContents());
        }
   }
   public ArrayList<String> getExcelKeyList()
   {
       return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: btw. if the OutOfMemory is in ExcelKeyList, then you can solve it using a "pager": Change the function so you can ask for chunks of 1000 cells instead of storing the whole table at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are surpassing the phone / tablet capacity. Just try to load the cells in chunks, like this:

```
        public class ReadExcelFile  {

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            Workbook myWorkBook;

            // open but not close, leave it open

            public void OpenExcelFile()
            {

                WorkbookSettings s = null;
                InputStream excelContent = null;
               try {
                    excelContent = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/product/sopho/lexiko.xls");
                    s = new WorkbookSettings();
                    s.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(true);
                    myWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(excelContent,s);

                } catch(Exception e) {

                } 

                // we leave it open

            }

            // close when you are done

            public void closeExcelFile() {
                if(myWorkBook != null) {
                    myWorkBook.close();
                }
            }

            // Once opened, get chunks calling ExcelKeyList(0,0,1000) .... etc

            private ArrayList<String> ExcelKeyList(int sheet,int startRow, int endRow)
            {
                Sheet sheet = myWorkBook.getSheet(sheet);       

                ExcelMap(sheet);
                ExcelKeyList(sheet);

                list.clear();

                for (int i=startRow; i<endRow; i++)
                {
                    list.add(sheet.getCell(0,i).getContents());
                }
                return list;
             }

             public ArrayList<String> getExcelKeyList()
             {
                 return list;
              }

        }
```

You have to find out what's the recommended chunk size before the phone explodes.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the out of memory is not in the excelkeylist.   ReadExcelFile file = new ReadExcelFile(); its like when it reads the file.